# Divide values in Python

Tags: python, python-2.x

I made a xlrd to json parsing script, which doesn't divide variables. It always returns zero... the code which I am using to divide the variables is:

```
if not row_values[2]:
   key['nr_one'] = 0
else:
   key['nr_one'] = int(row_values[2])
if not row_values[4]:
   key['nr_two'] = 0
else:     
   key['nr_two'] = int(row_values[4])
try:   
    key['perc'] = float(key['nr_two']/key['nr_one']*100)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    key['perc'] = 0
```

I have printed the following code at the end of the script:

```
print('one')
print(key['nr_one'])
print('two')
print(key['nr_two']) 
print('perc')
print(key['perc'])
```

This returns:

```
one
103386547
two
135680054
perc
0.0
```

So. I don't understand why the division fails and returns 0? Could someone please help me format a good way to calculate the percentage

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it should be `float(key['nr_two']) /key['nr_one']*100`

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Integer division is like this :

`1/3 #=> 0`

The easiest way to understand this result is not as a fraction, but as the answer to the question `"How many times do 3 fit in 1?"`.

So 0 multiplied by 100 is still :

`1/3 * 100 #=> 0`

You need

`100.0*1/3 #=> 33.333333`

For your code :

`key['perc'] = 100.0*key['nr_two']/key['nr_one']` (without using `float(...)`)

It returns :

`76.1987808465937`

NOTE: You really need to type `100.0` (a float), not just `100` (an int). You'd get `76` otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! My code however returns `76`.. and when I add a float it returns `76.0`. I will be using LFJ's answer but thank you very much!

Comment: See note at the end. You really need `100.0`, not just `100`

Answer (score 3):

`key['nr_two']` is integer and so is `key['nr_one']`. So when they are divided, the result is forced to be an integer **in Python 2x versions** (*in Python 3x this limitation does not exist and your code would run just fine*). What you therefore get, is 0, which is later multiplied by 100, so still 0 but float, 0.0.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve `float` division in python 2.x you can just add:

```
from __future__ import division
```

This way you will not need to convert your numbers each time you divide them.